# deleting the previous data in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database in which the table is getting populated periodically every hour. Now the data size has grown a lot.
I only want 10 days of data to be stored. All the rest to be deleted automatically every time a day has passed.

How can I do that in mysql?

Comment: what have u tried so long ??

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you search the internet ? 3 minutes in internet gave 

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,288225,288230#msg-288230

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: @AndrewAnderson - actually i didn't try anything before posting .sorry for that ..but your links are very useful .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options ..

Write a `cron job` to do this . (Using PHP/ASP/JSP - what ever you are working with)

Schedule an `Event` in mysql

```
CREATE EVENT `event_name`
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
DO BEGIN
    DELETE * FROM tablename WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 10 DAY
END;
```

for more info go to http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Otherwise have `trigger` for INSERT and delete the records accordingly (Problem here is for all insertion trigger will be called).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EVENT 'eventname' ON 
SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2013-01-09 10:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
COMMENT 'Clears out old data table each day.'
 DO 
      delete * from tablename WHERE fieldwithdateofinput < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

This will make a event triggered each 24 hour, starting the date 2013-01-09 10:00:00, assuming you have a field with the registered date when the input of that record was made (fieldwithdateofinput).

Comment: He is asking how will you set this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**1.Event Scheduler**

First create table and create event for perform delete query for delete 3 weeks ago record.

```
CREATE EVENT `ex1` ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO BEGIN
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 10

END
//for 3 weeks
```

Note : Old versions of mysql don't have event scheduler

**2. Create cron job**

file1.sql

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 10
```

**schedule this command:**

mysql -uusername -ppassword < /path/to/file1.sql